# To compile nested functions with Clang for elf_utils in Chromuim (Android)

Tags: android, c, gcc, chromium, ninja

I am trying to build Chromium Code for Android and getting stuck in compiling `elfutils` with 
`ninja -C opt/Full chrome_public_apk` command and I am getting this as exception

> [30/21982] CC
>   clang_x64/obj/third_party/elfutils/libelf/elf32_updatefile.o
>
> FAILED:
>   clang_x64/obj/third_party/elfutils/libelf/elf32_updatefile.o
>
> ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang -MMD -MF
>   clang_x64/obj/third_party/elfutils/libelf/elf32_updatefile.o.d
>   -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_PDF=1 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DUSE_UDEV -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DENABLE_MEDIA_ROUTER=1 -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=274369-1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_DEBUG -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DWTF_USE_DYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS=1 -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1 -I../../third_party/elfutils -I../../third_party/elfutils/src/lib -I../.. -Iclang_x64/gen -I../../third_party/elfutils/src/libelf -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wshadow -Werror -Wunused -Wextra -Wformat=2 -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fPIC -pipe -B../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -fcolor-diagnostics -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/vcareall/Yogesh/CompanyCode/chromium/src=. -pthread -m64 -march=x86-64 -O0 -g2 -gsplit-dwarf --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_wheezy_amd64-sysroot -fvisibility=hidden -Xclang -load -Xclang ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so
>   -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-templates -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang follow-macro-expansion -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-implicit-copy-ctors -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-ipc -Wheader-hygiene -Wstring-conversion -Werror -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-nonportable-include-path  -c ../../third_party/elfutils/src/libelf/elf32_updatefile.c -o
>   clang_x64/obj/third_party/elfutils/libelf/elf32_updatefile.o
>
> **../../third_party/elfutils/src/libelf/elf32_updatefile.c:297:4: error: function definition is not allowed here**
>
> {
>
> ^
>
> **../../third_party/elfutils/src/libelf/elf32_updatefile.c:331:7: error: implicit declaration of function 'fill_mmap' is invalid in C99
>   [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]**
>                        fill_mmap (dl->data.d.d_off);
>
> ^
>
> 2 errors generated.
>
> [35/21982] CXX
>   clang_x64/obj/third_party/android_protobuf/android_protoc/javamicro_file.o
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I am not familiar with working and configuring the `ninja` build system.
But I have read about `Clang` that it wont compile the nested functions and `G++` can do that. 
But I dont know how to set Ninja for running G++ to compile all nested function C code.

Anyone have any suggestion over it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compile code with nested functions with clang. From clang docs(https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#gcc-extensions-not-implemented-yet):

> clang does not support nested functions; this is a complex feature
>   which is infrequently used, so it is unlikely to be implemented
>   anytime soon.

To use g++ with ninja you can either change environmental variables CC and CXX, like this(unix-based os implied):

```
$ export CC=/path/to/gcc
$ export CXX=/path/to/g++
```

or change `clang` to `g++` in .ninja file if ninja doesn't use those variables.

Comment: thanks for help,but compiled successfully after few days of messing.